# How do you implement material design spec dimensions

Tags: android, material-design

Reading the material design spec, there are dimensions listed for padding, font size etc...
is there a univeral list of constants that i can use to incorporate in my app?
I can see things like:

```
 android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceListItemSmall"

  style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
```

Is there a universal way of accessing these names/constants? as right now seems painful trying to guess from the spec what the name of the constant is, (and where to find it)

Answer (score 1):

Default colors and dimens per Material Design guidelines and Android Design guidelines:

https://github.com/DmitryMalkovich/material-design-dimens

Example

```
@dimen/material_layout_keylines_screen_edge_margin
@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin
...
```